# Undefined method 'find' for [Fri, 20 Jan 2017]:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to loop on dates using group by, but I am getting this error.

> "Undefined method 'findings' for [Fri, 20 Jan 2017]:Array"

Controller:

```
def summary
  @date = Verif.all
  @sub_date = @date.group_by{|d| [d.Submit_Date]}
end
```

Model:

```
class Verif < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.findings
    Verif.where("Findings = ? or Findings = ?", 'FP','FN').count
  end

  def self.received
    Verif.where.not("App_ID", '').count
  end

  def self.tp
    Verif.where("Findings = ?", 'TP').count
  end

end
```

Views:

```
    <tr id="thead-value">
       <td><%= @sub_date.each do |date|%></td>
       <% for ds in date %>
         <td><%= ds.findings%></td>
         <td><%= ds.received%></td>
         <td><%= ds.tp%></td>
    </tr>
```

I am very very new to rails. Thank you in advance!

Comment: on which line exactly the error is raised?

Comment: on this one <td><%= ds.findings%></td>

Comment: there are multiple errors here firstly, do not group_by array, just do `@date.group_by{|d| d.Submit_Date }` although it will solve current issue but raise another...what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to display a table where it will count the number of datas per date. 
Example:
Submit_Date | Findings | Received
 2017-01-01   |   15        |    40

Answer (score 1):

From controller:

```
def summary
  @date = Verif.all
  @sub_date = @date.group_by{|d| [d.Submit_Date]}
end
```

Line:

```
@sub_date = @date.group_by{|d| [d.Submit_Date]}
```

will result in this:

```
#=> {["Fri, 20 Jan 2017"] => [d1, d2], ...}
```

So when we use it in your view:

```
@sub_date.each do |date| # date will be the key: ["Fri, 20 Jan 2017"]
```

Hence the exception for the undefined method.

To solve this, we just need to use key and value in `each` like so:

```
@sub_date.each do |_, date| # date will be the value: [d1, d2... ]
                            # and key will be ignored because of a "_"
```

Comment: I got the error "undefined method `findings' for #<Verif:0x007fcabebf12e8>"

Comment: Check if you have `findings` column in verifs table.

Comment: None, i was trying to call an class method from my model.